# Linux Mint shows different total file size than Android? (in bytes)

Tags: filesystems

I have a directory with some photos and videos.

If I enter `ls -l --block-size=1` on Linux (saved on NTFS HDD), then I get a slightly different total size (in bytes) than using ES File Explorer, yet every single file matches in hash sums and there is no extra hidden file such as thumbs.db.

Comment: Is the output of ES in bytes or K-bytes or M-bytes? And give us an example of the numbers.

Comment: Dierctory size difference?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor In bytes! Not kB/KiB/etc. I mean bytes. I will post example numbers.

Comment: Did I say “Dierctory size difference”? @V-Mark. I mean the contents of a directory.

Comment: I mean directories have size.
If you make an empty directory, it is 1 block (eg.: 4k).
If you copy many files in that directory, it will grow to 2-3-... blocks.
Likely this is shown in different ways your 2 listings.

Comment: From the beginning:
Dont't you have subdirectories in that directory?
I mean those subdirectories themselves, not the content of the directory.